# looking to buy a 2000 ford expedition with broken ignition. it doesn"t run but running prior. how do i repair it

Tags: electrical, ford, ignition, security, expedition

Thinking of buying at 2000 ford expedition. The keys where lost to this vehicle. they tried to hammer out ignition causing anti theft light to come on. The vehicle does not run. Before this the vehicle was running. How do i repair this so i can drive it?. obviously the ignition needs replacement. i plan on buying complete column , but do i need to reset anti theft? is this done buy disconnecting battery and sequence of procedures? what would this be? do i need replacement part? what steps need to be taken to ensure that buying parts is done thoroughly as to limit trips? just as easy to return as purchase and less frustration of not being able to have positive outcome.

Comment: You want "*less frustration of not being able to have positive outcome*"? Don't buy someone else's mess. What you are getting into is bound to be challenging, along with some frustration.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look for a different truck. It's 17 years old at this point and If the owner was willing to "Hammer out the ignition" to try and start the car... Who knows what else is really wrong with it.

If it's only the lock cylinder that's damaged than replace it and get some new keys from the dealer to minimize problems. If you want to replace the whole column just make sure it's complete (lock cylinder, switch, harness, transceiver and key(s)).

You need to have a EOBD2 or OE scantool with bi-directional controls or the original master keys to program new keys.

Answer (score 0):

If it was an easy repair, the owner would have done it - considering they were trying a non standard solution then avoid it.

There is a similar question asked recently...:

[Can I switch my electronic ignition to one which uses a key?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/48460/can-i-switch-my-electronic-ignition-to-one-which-uses-a-key)